# Startup Disk Creator does not exist

Tags: boot, usb

As Ubuntu [docs](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#3-launch-startup-disk-creator) says, we need to launch `Startup Disk Creator` to create a bootable Ubuntu.

But when I search for it the screen stucks at *Searching...*

[image]

And no matter how much I wait, it won't find it.

What should I do?

Update: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This is the `echo /etc/os-release`:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is probably a language barrier. I think we have different native languages, but the search method you tried did not work for me, yet the tool is there with a 'translated' name (for me 'Skapa uppstartsdisk'). But the file name `usb-creator-gtk` can be found, actually it is enough to type "usb" in the search window to find it. See the screenshot (where also 'my own' [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) tools are shown).

You can also find it by the following command line in a terminal window,

```
which usb-creator-gtk
```

and *run it* with the command

```
usb-creator-gtk
```

[image]

**Edit 1:** If for some reason there is no Startup Disk Creator in your system, you can install it with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

and the current version (**0.3.13**, now, 2022-06-23, in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) can be found by

```
sudo apt-cache policy usb-creator-gtk
```

**Edit 2:** If you install a minimal Ubuntu system, there will be no Startup Disk Creator. Thanks to the original poster of this thread, Saeed Neamati, for sharing this observation :-)

Comment: Using `usb` did not work for me. Again got stuck at *Searching...*. Using `which usb-creator-gtk` returns nothing. And running `usb-creator-gtk` also does nothing. I also upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and even then all of the above is still true for me.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, It seems my conclusions based on my own observations failed. Anyway, you can install the tool with `sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk` into current versions. In an up to date installed system of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the version of usb-creator-gtk is 0.3.13. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Did you install a minimal Ubuntu system? It could explain why there is no Startup Disk Creator. Or did you or someone else remove it? It it part of a standard installation.

Comment: Yes. I installed the minimal version. OMG.

Comment: How can I tell the ubuntu team to include it in their documentation? It took me many hours and I could not solve it. Thus I used another tool.

Comment: 1. Via a bug report at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net); or 2. via a question at [Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: By the way, you are probably missing several other standard tools too. I think it should be fixed by `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`; it is a meta-package that should bring 'everything' that belongs to the Ubuntu Desktop system.

Comment: thank you so much. Though I prefer to stay lean. I don't need other tools.

Comment: OK, good luck with your lean system :-) I keep my main system lean by installing Lubuntu instead of standard Ubuntu Desktop. There are many ways to get the system we want.

Comment: to launch the startup disk creator I had to use the CLI as above, no search results as advertised.  I had installed the regular desktop version.  Anyhow, it's at least easy to launch once you know the command.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders, Which version (22.04.x LTS or another version of Ubuntu Desktop) are you running? And which locale and keyboard (language and flavour of language)?

Comment: 22.04 @sudodus as I recall, and English for keyboard, etc.  Just seemed worth mentioning.  It's an excellent tool.  (On a diff pc at the moment.)

Comment: @NicholasSaunders, I'm surprised that you won't find the Startup Disk Creator the 'GUI' way, when using English in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. But I'm glad that it works via the command line.

Comment: I dist-upgraded to 22.04 (from 20.04) and my Startup Disk Creator disappeared, so I had to run sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk to get it back, which worked.

Comment: I suspect minimal installation does not include `usb-creator-gtk` since that's how I setup my system with Ubuntu 22.04 and I don't have it. It's available on the repositories, though.

Answer (score 6):

If you have accidentally removed the default `Startup Disk Creator` or it is not present on your system you can reinstall it from the `Ubuntu Software` application[image]